# Cannot connect to MySQL server Azure from python

Tags: python, mysql

I've been trying to connect to a MySQL database remotely but I keep getting the error:

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'local.mysql.database.azure.com:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1045)
```

Using the exact same connection details I am able to connect to the database through MySQL Workbench and through Node. For some reason the connection won't go through in python.

This user's as not created to require SSL.

I've been trying to figure out the problem but I'm drawing blanks.

Below is my python login block.

```
config = {
  'host':'local.mysql.database.azure.com',
  'user':'user@local',
  'password':'password',
  'database':'random_db'
}
```

I've been able to connect to a MySQL instance on the Google Cloud Platform with the exact same connection block but it doesn't work for the Azure connection. I've looked for differences between the two platforms which could have caused this and the only thing I could find was that the Azure MySQL version was 5.7.32log while the GCP was 8.0.18.

I am also currently running python 3.7.0, not sure if that changes anything.

Is there another module I could use if that is the problem, or do I need to downgrade something? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-version-policy) 5.7.29 is the latest 5.7 supported so 5.7.32 would give wrong version error.